# entire page get posted back even with ajax [rails]

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

What I'm doing should be pretty simple, I have page that display all records if request was http and get recrods between dates if it was ajax.
here how the page looks [image]

this is index.html.erb

```
<h1>Jobs History</h1>
<hr>
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= label_tag(:start_date) %>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
      <%= text_field_tag :start_date , "", {class:'form-control'} %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
    </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= label_tag(:end_date) %>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
      <%= text_field_tag :end_date , "", {class:'form-control'} %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
    </div>
      </div>
    <a id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-skin btn-md"  href="#">Search</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="items_grid" >
<%= render partial: 'histories', locals: {bookings: @bookings} %>
</div>


<script>
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
  $('a#searchBtn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "<%= provider_history_index_path %>",
      type: "GET",
      data: {start_date: $('#start_date').val(), end_date: $('#end_date').val()},
      success: function(resp){ }
    });
  });

</script>
```

pretty normal right and here the controller:

```
   respond_to :html, :js
  def index
    if request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        @bookings = current_user.booking_providers.where(visit_end_date:     params[:start_date]..params[:end_date])
        format.js
      end
    else
      @bookings = current_user.booking_providers
    end
```

and here index.js.erb

```
$("#items_grid").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'histories', locals: { bookings: @bookings} ) %>");
```

the problem is when I fill the dates and click on search, the ajax fire up and does render the partial with new records but after that immediately index get called and full page postback happens which overwrite the new records.
I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer from reddit user jemminger, in case somebody have similar problem

the reason is because I was intercepting the submit so that I can perform an ajax call, but I was not preventing the default behavior of the form posting normally.
Every jQuery click handler receives an event. Call preventDefault() on the event.

```
$('a#searchBtn').click(function(evt){ /* <--- the event object is passed to your handler by jQuery */
  evt.preventDefault();  /* <--- stop it from performing its normal behavior */

  $.ajax({
    url: "<%= provider_history_index_path %>",
    type: "GET",
    data: {start_date: $('#start_date').val(), end_date: $('#end_date').val()},
    success: function(resp){ }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the routes for the index and your ajax call. Alternatively, you MUST render something in the `if request.xhr?` block and return.
When you `GET provider_history_index_path` the index action being called.

Rails uses "convention over configuration", so controllers in Rails automatically render views with names that correspond to valid routes.

In your case Rails renders index.html.erb after all.

related thread: [Rails checkbox AJAX call, don't want to render anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380300/rails-checkbox-ajax-call-dont-want-to-render-anything)